# What elements/concepts are found in this piece of javascript?

Tags: javascript, element, identify

Was messing around and found this to be handy for some stuff but if ya had to ask me what exactly is what right now, I wouldn't be able to tell you, so was wondering if the community could help identify elements and concepts in the following...

```
 var MyStuff = {

    STATS: {
            SHOTS:0,
            TRIES:0,
            HIGHESTSCORE:0,
            LIVESLOST:0
    },

    defaultLevel: 0,

    players: [
            {
                    name: 'Chuck',
                    surname: 'Norris',
                    punchline: 'Chuck Norris can set ants on fire with a magnifying glass, At night.',
                    dateCreated: '10/03/2011'
            },
            {
                    name: 'Mr',
                    surname: 'T',
                    punchline: 'I pity the fool who drinks soy milk.',
                    dateCreated: '10/03/2011'
            }
    ],

    startGame: function() {

            alert("You shouldn't have come back, " + this.players[0].surname);
            alert("" + this.players[1].punchline);
            this.STATS.SHOTS = 0;
            this.STATS.LIVESLOST = 1000000000000;
            var smiles = this.STATS.LIVESLOST;
            //TODO - More stuff
    }
}

var KaPow = MyStuff;
```

*Usage:*

```
    KaPow.startGame();
    alert("Starting Level: " + KaPow.defaultLevel);
    alert("Player 1: " + KaPow.players[0].name + " " + KaPow.players[0].surname);
    alert("Player 2: " + KaPow.players[1].name + " " + KaPow.players[1].surname);
    alert("Score: " + KaPow.STATS.LIVESLOST);
```

Comment: So what do you want to know? You want what this piece does? Or you want to understand the construct of java script used here?

Comment: -> "understand the construct" ;)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript objects as defined by the {};
JavaScript arrays as defined by the [];

Nesting objects and arrays inside each other;

Defining functions as part of an object;

Answer (score 1):

You've made an object called MyStuff (which you've also assigned to KaPow).

It's got a bunch of properties (STATS, dificultyLevel, Players), and a function (startGame).  Some of those properties are themselves objects (like STATS and Players) and so on and so forth.  STATS, for example, has its own properties (SHOTS, SCORE, TRIES, LIVESLOST)

The function, startgame, can operate on the object's properties since it is within the scope of the object (i.e. this.players[0]).